# Java Spring DI not working with Java Configuration

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I'm new to Java Spring and trying to use Java configuration and inject a dependency into a class constructor. I want to use constructor injection because the class methods require the dependency. It isn't working for me.

Use case: Create a JSON string from a Java object and validate it before returning.

Class: FakeJsonBuilder

Dependency: JsonValidator

Main class: Per Spring documentation the @SpringBootApplication annotation is a convenience annotation that adds @Configuration, @EnableAutoConfiguration and @ComponentScan so I should be good to go as far as dependency injection is concerned.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MySpringApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        // Register the class we use for Java based configuration
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context =
                new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        context.register(ApplicationConfiguration.class);
        context.refresh();

        SpringApplication.run(MySpringApplication .class, args);
    }
}
```

Java configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public JsonValidator jsonValidator(){
        return new JsonValidatorImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public JsonBuilder(){
        return new FakeJsonBuilder();
    }
}
```

FakeJsonBuilder class:

```
public class FakeJsonBuilder implements JsonBuilder{

    private static Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(FakeJsonBuilder.class);
    private static JsonValidator jsonValidator;

    // I need an empty constructor for the ApplicationConfiguration setup to work.
    public MlrModelJsonBuilder(){};

    @Autowired
    public FakeJsonBuilder (JsonValidator jsonValidator){
        this.jsonValidator = jsonValidator;

        boolean validatorInjected = (jsonValidator != null);
        logger.info("Validator injected: " + validatorInjected);
    }

.......... More methods
```

The jsonValidator dependency is not being injected, i.e. the log message is **Validator injected: false**

Comment: did u try autowiring JsonValidator in FakeJsonBuilder class

Comment: From https://web.archive.org/web/20111120115551/http://springindepth.com/book/in-depth-ioc-autowiring.html "any constructor argument or property explicitly set will not be eligible for autowiring."

Comment: UPDATE: Testing Pankaj suggestion I updated FakeJsonBuilder to remove the constructor and created an autowired method that takes the JsonValidator interface as an argument  and returns FakeJsonBuilder and the injection is successful. HOWEVER that fails the objective of injecting the dependency into the constructor.

Comment: Its fine ...you dont anyways need the constructor

Comment: Doing it right is doing it right Pankaj. If the class methods _require_ the dependency it should be injected into the controller. This would be trivial with Ninject.

Comment: Why are you creating a `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` yourself but then also creating a `SpringApplication`? Your `@Configuration` class clearly creates a `FakeJsonBuilder` using a parameterless constructor so I don't see how or why you expect the constructor that expects an argument to be invoked. I don't know where that output comes from but it's not from the code you've posted.

Comment: Sotirios: "Why are you creating a AnnotationConfigApplicationContext yourself but then also creating a SpringApplication? " Answer: because I'm pretty sure that's the way it's supposed to work. And, in fact, as of a few minutes ago, it does indeed work for me. Issue was that I needed () after the interface in the configuration class. I will post some sample code ASAP

Comment: Doing `new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();` creates an `ApplicationContext` where all your beans reside. Doing `SpringApplication.run(...)` creates another `ApplicationContext` in the background where more beans reside. Both are completely independent and, in this case, seemingly redundant.

Comment: Also it's still unclear where the corresponding constructor for this `new FakeJsonBuilder();` is. You've only shown one constructor for that class and it expects an argument.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting Martin: Fowler http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html
*"My long running default with objects is as much as possible, to create valid objects at construction time. This advice goes back to Kent Beck's Smalltalk Best Practice Patterns: Constructor Method and Constructor Parameter Method. Constructors with parameters give you a clear statement of what it means to create a valid object in an obvious place. If there's more than one way to do it, create multiple constructors that show the different combinations."*

I come from a .NET background and use Ninject to inject my dependencies into the class constructor for the reasons Fowler gives. I quoted Fowler because of his credibility but you will find many sources providing the same argument, i.e. if the class methods require the dependency then it should be injected into the constructor. So here's how I figured how to do it with Java Spring (I revert to my C# syntax - forgive the transgression):

**The configuration class**

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public IJsonValidator jsonValidator(){
        return new JsonValidator();
    }

    @Bean
    public IJsonBuilder jsonBuilder(){
        return new JsonBuilder(jsonValidator());
    }
}
```

**The class into which we inject the dependency**

```
public class JsonBuilder implements IJsonBuilder {

    private static IJsonValidator _jsonValidator;

    // @Autowired // not needed per Sotirios. tested and verified
    public JsonBuilder(IJsonValidator jsonValidator) {
        _jsonValidator = jsonValidator;
    }

    public String getFoobar() {

        // Returns false. jsonValidator was injected
        boolean foo = (_jsonValidator == null);

        return "Validator was injected: " + foo;
    }

... more methods
```

Comment: You don't need `@Autowired` on the constructor if you're generating the bean instances yourself with `@Bean` factory methods.